# Find the residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 \sin z}$ at the point $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

My idea is find the Laurent Series first but I have no idea to find it. So after receive some hints, I first have $\sin z = z(1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} +\ldots)$. Then by geometry series, I have $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} +\ldots} = \frac{1}{z^3}(1 + (\frac{z^2}{3!} +\ldots) + \ldots)$ . Then I have found that Res$(f(z),z=0) = \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{6}$. It is the way to find the Residue?

Comment: Are you sure in the Laurent series you wrote? It says that $f(0)=0$

Comment: @EgorIvanov Sorry I did a mistake, is the Laurent series correct right now?

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: @EgorIvanov I use $sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - ... $ then  $\frac{1}{sin(z)} = \frac{1}{z(1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - ... } =  \frac{1}{z\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}$.Then multiply $\frac{1}{z^3}$ we have that.

Comment: I am afraid you supposed that $(\sin z)^{-1}=\sin (z^{-1})$, that is not true :(

Comment: Something similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266716/residue-fracezz3-sinz?rq=1

Comment: @EgorIvanov I try to use another way to find it, but is the way to compute Laurent series is correct?

Comment: @geetha290krm I got it and the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$, thanks

Comment: Here you can see how to calculate correctly the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648923/calculate-laurent-series-for-1-sinz Then it should be pretty straightforward :)

Comment: @user773458 ok thanks